# Was passed main parameter 'desc' but no main parameter was defined

Tags: java, jcommander

I was receiving the below error, when a try to pass the jar parameters like:

```
--order-by serialnumber, to_timestamp(startdate) desc
```

com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed main parameter 'desc' but no main parameter was defined

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem a did:

```
--order-by "serialnumber, to_timestamp(startdate) desc"
```